# Bitbake Congatec Yocto - hangs in step: parsing recipes. git ls-remote http://<user>:<key>@host/project hangs

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Everything worked before. But at one point everything got stuck at the step of parsing recipes. How can i fix it?

```
./clear_mntconti_cpp.sh 
source /opt/yocto/.yocto_build.rocko/poky/oe-init-build-env /opt/yocto/.yocto_build.rocko/build && \
bitbake -r /opt/yocto/.yocto_build.rocko/build/conf/bblayers_before.conf -c cleansstate -f  mntconti-tracker && \
bitbake -r /opt/yocto/.yocto_build.rocko/build/conf/bblayers_before.conf -c clean -f mntconti-tracker && \
bitbake -r /opt/yocto/.yocto_build.rocko/build/conf/bblayers_before.conf -c cleanall -f  mntconti-tracker 

### Shell environment set up for builds. ###

You can now run 'bitbake <target>'

Common targets are:
    core-image-minimal
    core-image-sato
    meta-toolchain
    meta-ide-support

You can also run generated qemu images with a command like 'runqemu qemux86'
Parsing recipes:   0% |#                                                                                                                                                                     | ETA:  0:01:12
```

Update:
I find that this command

```
git ls-remote http://<user>:<key>@host/project
```

are hangs, and i have no idea why...

Comment: how long have you left it to wait? Also, using `top`/`htop` to check whether a process is eating all CPU or whether you're blocked on something else would be a logical next step

Comment: @MarcusMüller about 20 minutes. I look on htop and see, that bitbake call git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 ls-remote http://<user>:<key>@project.git and hangs. I think problem in this moment

Comment: That sounds like a network problem, or the remote server letting you wait. bitbake seems to be trying to figure out remotes

Comment: @MarcusMüller find solution, it was problem with git access, after update

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in git access, after git update. So, bitbake hangs on ls-remote command.

I figured out I needed to look at that after looking at the process list shown by `htop`.

How i detect it. I started bitbake script and it hangs. Then i opened htop and saw, that bitbake call process such

```
git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 ls-remote http://user:pwd@host/project
```

I call this process separate and saw, that its hangs. So, when i call bitbake it was hangs, because it waiting result from git forever.

In git after update rules for file  /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/sockets/socket was invalid. But after set all permission it not still work. But it works afetr add user gitlab-www in group git

Comment: great! Added a bit of background how you figured that out, in hopes it helps future readers debug their builds!